# Not getting index for D3 Pie layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Below if my code. I am using the D3 Pie layout, and have no problem getting the data values here as d, but the index i is coming out as undefined. Is there a way to get the index of the data element?

```
var g = svg.append('g').selectAll('.innerArc')
          .data(pie(data.values))
          .enter()
          .append('path')
          .attr('d', arc)
          .attr('fill', function(d, i) {return getColor(d.data, i) })
          .attr('stroke', function(d, i) {return getColor(d.data, i); });
```

This is how I'm generating the pie layout.

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .value(function(d) { return d.value; })
      .sort(null);
```

Comment: It shouldn't. Could you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: OK, I added some more info, but is there some way to get the index of the datum? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, use `i`. It shouldn't be undefined. There are plenty of examples, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/ragingsquirrel3/qkHK6/

Answer (score 0):

`i` was not working for me, I got around it by adding the index to my data object, then retrieving it by using `d.data.index`